# Passing variables into views

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a new learner of Laravel,and currently I am playing with views. However,after passing a variable in my view,I get this exception. Basically it's saying that the route doesn't exist.

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in    
CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),    
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

So here is what I am doing

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('show_comment/{$id}','CommentsController@showComment');
```

**CommentsController.php**

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{

}
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    return "inside Create method";
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return "Show method:" .$id;
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    //
  }


public function destroy($id)
{
    //

}

public function contact(){
    return view('contacts');
}


public function showComment($id){
    return view('show_comment') -> with('id',$id);
  }

}
```

And finally I have my simple view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Laravel</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100"    
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1/>Show comment {{$id}}}</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Routes.php should be show_comment/{id} instead of {$id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Xatenev said in the comments, it should just be a case of removing `$` in the route so changing:

```
Route::get('show_comment/{$id}','CommentsController@showComment');
```

to:

```
Route::get('show_comment/{id}','CommentsController@showComment');
```